# Comparing two arrays in java and return number of equalities

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I'm currently writing a small function which should return how many items of an array are exactly on the same position as the other array and how many are there but on different positions.

the function currently looks like this:

```
public static int[] numCorrects(char[] leftarray, char[] rightarray){
    int counter[] = new int[2];
    counter[0] = 0;
    counter[1] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < leftarray.length; i++) {
        if(leftarray[i]==rightarray[i]) counter[0]++;
        else {
            for (int n = 0; n < leftarray.length; n++) {
                if (leftarray[i] == rightarray[n] && leftarray[n] != rightarray[n]) {
                    counter[1]++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

This works kinda well if i have lets say the `leftarray` of `(1, 2, 3, 4)` and the `rightarray` of `(4, 3, 2, 2)`

it the returns `(0, 3)` (0 exact match, 3 there but on different position)

but now the problem:

if I swap the inputs with `leftarray` of `(4, 3, 2, 2)` and `rightarray` of `(1, 2, 3, 4)` the output is `(0, 4)` which is wrong (should be the same as the 1st one)

hope anyone can help me. thx

Comment: You can loose the leftarray[n] != rightarray[n], you already checked before if the elements on the same index are the same. And considering you are in that piece of code, they were not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public static int[] numCorrects(char[] leftarray, char[] rightarray){
    int counter[] = new int[2];
    counter[0] = 0;
    counter[1] = 0;
    boolean taken[] = new boolean[rightarray.length];
    for (int i=0;i<taken.length;i++)
        taken[i] = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < leftarray.length; i++) {
        if(leftarray[i]==rightarray[i]){ counter[0]++; taken[i] = true; }
        else {
            for (int n = 0; n < leftarray.length; n++) {
                if (leftarray[i] == rightarray[n] && leftarray[n] != rightarray[n] && !taken[n]) {
                    taken[n] = true;
                    counter[1]++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: I edited code. to set taken for if (leftarray[i]==rightarray[i])

Comment: wait this is wrong. we must do first case alone with a loop(same place). then the other case alone in a loop. let me fix.

Comment: I added another answer. check it. its more logical. its longer but you can decrease length later. we can delete this answer if the other one is the right one.

Comment: ok hmm tried it. it fixes the problem with the given example. but not if the first array is like `(2, 2, 2, 5)` and the 2nd sth like `(1, 2, 2, 4)` i get sth like `(1, 2)` which should be `(0, 2)`

Comment: (2, 2, 2, 5) (1, 2, 2, 4) should give (2, 0) and that what the other code do. 2 at same place and 0 not in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide how to handle repeated elements. This is what's causing the discrepancy. The repeated `2` means that the "different positions" counter is incremented twice when the arrays are swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the break and you will get the same result.

Comment: Yes the same result no matter the input order, but both time not the correct one. i cannot have more than 4 matches if I the array is only of length 4. without the break it would count some values twice.

Comment: Then you should implement a way to check if you already have processed that number before.  Put the processed ones in a HashMap or something like that, and before comparing it to the other array, check if that number isn't in the HashMap yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] numCorrects(char[] leftarray, char[] rightarray){
    int counter[] = new int[2];
    counter[0] = 0;
    counter[1] = 0;
    boolean taken[] = new boolean[rightarray.length];
    for (int i=0;i<taken.length;i++)
        taken[i] = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < leftarray.length; i++) {
        if(leftarray[i]==rightarray[i])
        {
            counter[0]++;
            taken[i]=true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < leftarray.length; i++)
    {
        if (!taken[i])
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rightarray.length; j++) {
                if (leftarray[i] == rightarray[j] && i!=j && !taken[j]) { // you can remove i!=j because its already don't apply because of !taken[i]
                    taken[j] = true;
                    counter[1]++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: I am supposing that you are implementing that popular game.

Comment: to know what I mean try the following for the two answers: 1 1 3 4 and 5 1 6 7. check for both codes and you decide.

Comment: If this work accept this one and upvote. I will delete the other one.